# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje si un dato no existe en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Tengo una variable `$buscarcolor=$_REQUEST['color'];` y otra para la consulta:

```
$registros=mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from tenis where Color='$buscarcolor'") or die ("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
```

y luego un bucle:

```
while($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{   
    echo "Modelo del producto: ".$reg['Modelo']."<br>";
    echo "Talla del producto: ".$reg['Talla']."<br>";
    echo "Precio del producto: ".$reg['Precio']."<br>";
    echo "ID del producto: ".$reg['ID']."<br>";
    echo "Descuento disponible: ".$reg['Descuento']."%"."<br>";
    echo "Marca del producto: ".$reg['Marca']."<br>";
    echo "Color del producto: ".$reg['Color']."<br>"."<br>";
}
```

Necesito una condición o algo para que cuando no haya un `'Color'` en `$buscarcolor` muestre el mensaje:

> "No hay tenis de color ".$buscarcolor." disponibles en tienda"

Comment: En ese caso, no hagas un die, y cuenta cuantos valores ha retornado la consulta. Si retorna 0, es por que no devolvió nada, y despliegas el mensaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo optimo seria validar si existen resultados.
Contar si hay respuestas, esto se logra implementado la propiedad `num_rows` del resultado `mysqli_query`:

Ejemplo:

```
$buscarcolor = $_REQUEST['color'];
$query = "select * from tenis where Color='$buscarcolor'";
$res = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
if($res->num_rows > 0){
    [....]
}else{
    echo "No hay registros devueltos";
}
```

Comment: Pasa que cuando se ejecuta el "else" no imprime nada en pantalla... Y gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si el else no se imprime, es por que tienes algo devuelto. Haz esto, un var_dump($res) para ver si la respuesta obtuvo algo o no. Y confirmar la información

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Ya lo noté, no era field_count, es num_rows... corregiré eso, gracias por la insistencia.

Comment: Te quiero mucho, ya pude jajajaja

Comment: De nada jaja :3

Answer (score -1):

```
//tu query
$sql = "select * from tenis where Color='.$buscarcolor.'";

//indicas que tu query lo quieres ejecutar en tu conexión previamente configurada $conn

if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

//Si tu query recibe mas de 0 resultados entonces haces tu instrucción

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

     //Fila por fila vas obteniendo los resultados y muestras los que necesites únicamente dentro de este while

     while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

     $modelo=$fila['Modelo'];
     $talla=$fila['Talla'];

     //Continuas llamando todas las columnas de tu tabla que requieras

     echo $modelo.'<br>';
     echo $talla...
     }

     //si tu conexión y tu query esta bien entonces todo se ejecuta perfectamente y recibes tu $result

     mysqli_free_result($result);
   } else{

     //Si no ningún error en tu query ni tu conexión pero tampoco hayregistros en tu tabla te muestra esto

     echo "No se encontró ninguna fila";
  }
} else{

//Si tienes un error en tu consulta o conexión aquí se despliega un hint

echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Esperando a que esto te ayude a resolver lo que buscas.

Comment: creo que tu respuesta es un poco confusa o poco legible, saludos.

Comment: Se ha editado el código, ayúdame a entender, si la razón por la que es confusa es por los comentarios.

Comment: Si en teoría la manera en que los dejaste inicialmente no se lograba distinguir entre código y comentario; tambien deberías agregar fuera del código una explicación de lo que planteas te dejo este articulo de lectura: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios @Francisco, los tendré en cuenta para mis futuras respuestas.

Comment: Mira, te ayudaré a mejorar la respuesta. Tu y yo apuntamos al mismo objetivo. La gran diferencia, es que la mía se resume en un par de líneas de explicación, más el código directamente. No es necesario explicar todo, sino solo el detalle que el OP necesita.